# Image path is not store in table field as a string from fileupload

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, dotnetnuke

i have use ascx it contain fileupload control to get the selected image path as a string in data base table filed using linq, and ascx is used in dotnetnuke module page.
there is code which i have use in my ascx.cs but it not get the image path from fileupload control

```
        FormViewRow row = FormView1.Row;
        FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)row.FindControl("FileUpload1");

        string filename = "";
        string path;
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            path = Server.MapPath("DesktopModules/IndiesStore/Images/")+               
            FileUpload1.FileName;
            string onlyname = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

            IC.Img = "DesktopModules/IndiesStore/Images/" + onlyname;

        }
```

there is an any solution of this....?

Comment: Did you check the `/` & `\\` that you have used. Try by changing them.

Comment: can you got value in "path" variable?

Comment: ya it gives the full root path of selected image

Answer (score 0):

ya but it worked directly like that code

```
    FormViewRow row = FormView1.Row;
    FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)row.FindControl("FileUpload1");

    string filename = "";
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        IC.Img = "DesktopModules/IndiesStore/Images/" + filename;

    }
```

so it is solved, 
user have to just place the all images on same folder on server and select the images in fileupload from there so it work properly.